# CSS - how to get one element from the div with smaller z-index above the content of the other div with higher z-index

Tags: css, algolia

How can I get, if it is possible, one element from the div with the lower z-index above the content of the div with higher z-index?
In my template I have a wrapper for all of the content on the page, and an off-canvas menu that is hidden on the right side:

```
@section('head')
  @include('public.layouts.partials._head')
@show
@include('public.layouts.partials._menu')
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    @include('public.layouts.partials._navigation')
      @yield('content')
    @include('public.layouts.partials._footer')
  </div>
</div>
```

In my navigation partial I have an input field with algolia autocomplete:

```
   <div class="form-wrapper">
     <form action="/search" method="get">
       <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
           <button type="submit" class="search-button">
             <i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i>
           </button>
         </span>
         <input type="text" name="q" class="search-input search-input-small-js form-control aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for players and videos ..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
```

The problem I have is, that when I open the menu, if I type in something in the field, the results will show below the menu. What I would like to do is to somehow, if possible show the dropdown menu from the autocomplete field above all of the content  on the page.
This is the css for the off-canvas menu:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
        color: $dark-green;
        padding: 45px;
        padding-top: 3rem;
        background: $black-menu-bg;
        a {
            color: $light-gray;
        }
        h4 {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .btn {
        margin-top: 1rem;
      }
}
.push-menu-left {
    top: 50px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
        box-shadow: 4px 2px 3px hsla(0,0%,4%,.5);
}
.push-menu-left {
    right: -285px;
}
body.pml-open .push-menu-left {
    right: 0;
}
body.pml-open #wrapper {
    right: 280px;
}
```

And this is the css for the autocomplete field:

```
.algolia-autocomplete {
  display: flex!important;
  flex: auto!important;
}
.aa-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: $white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.aa-dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  left: 24px;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu .aa-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu [class^="aa-dataset-"] {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #3c3e42;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aa-suggestion {
  padding: 0 4px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  clear: both;
}
.aa-suggestion span {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.aa-suggestion.aa-cursor {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.aa-suggestion em {
  color: #00bcd4;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.aa-suggestion img {
  float: left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.aa-suggestion a {
  color: #3c3e42;
}

.aa-suggestions-category {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3c3e42;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
}

.powered-by-algolia {
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.aa-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
.aa-input-search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px 28px 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; }
.aa-input-search::-webkit-search-decoration, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}
.media {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.media-body {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's easier to tinker around with z-index if you make this into a codepen/fiddle, could you do that?

Comment: Yes there is. set the z-index for the aa-dropdown-menu class to whatever value you need. It defaults to 100.